# What does "The Hilbert space carries a representation of [...] group" means?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, mathematical-physics

Often, in quantum mechanics I found the sentence "The Hilbert space carries a representation of $SU(2)$ group" (in particular when dealing with anglar momenta).

Effectively, I know that this means that the eigenvectors of some operators ${({\bf J})^2}$ 
span the Hilbert space and they can be a base for the vector space. Where $\bf{(J)^2}$ is the Casimir ${\bf (J)^2}=J_x^2+J_y^2+J_z^2$ and ${\bf J}$ belongs to the algebra of $su(2)$, namely *e.g.* $[J_x,J_y]=J_z$ etc.

But what does it means in general in terms of representation theory?

Comment: It means there's a group homomorphism $\mathop{\text{SU}}(2)\to \mathop{\text{Aut}}(H)$, the automorphism group of the Hilbert space.